# Lightbox and swf nav question

Tags: flash, lightbox

Can anyone tell me why lightbox isn't working on my page?? It works when i test it dreamweaver but as soon as i load it, it stops working. You click on one of the pictures and the flash navigation disappears. I've been working on this for hours so i'm lost as to what to try next. Thanks.

http://www.shellyfairchild.net/pages/photos.html

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at this real quickly - found a couple things going on that definitely will mess you up. First off, just debug this page and you get a potent error "Builder is not defined" - this means something is wrong with how you are linking Scriptaculous (I haven't spent any time with either, so the fix is up to you, but thats where your problem is). Check that out and it should fix your lightbox issue.

Your flash is disappearing because your are setting its visiblity to hidden - I assume because flash will float over lightbox and it seemed like a good idea at the time. And honestly, if you are just using flash for a simple rollover, then its the wrong tech for the job. A simple javascript rollover will be much simpler to use, and function exactly the same.

Hope that helps point you in the right direction.